# Sum of Lengths of each closed interval in the Cantor Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I wanted to show that by mathematical induction that sum of lengths of each closed interval in the Cantor set is equal to $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}$. It is easy to show that it hold for the base case however, I am stuck at showing that it hold for $n=k+1$. I hope anyone can give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We simply use ratios. Each segment of $C_n$ is trisected and the middle third is taken away. As a result, the length of the segment now becomes $\frac{2}{3}$ of its original size. The same happens for all segments of $C_n$. Thus, the sum of lengths in $C_{n+1}$ is two-thirds of that of $C_n$, as required to prove.